# CUDA implementation for MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, cuda, mex, ptx

I have recently purchased a P100 GPU in hopes of speeding up parallel code and need some help deciding how to translate MATLAB code into a CUDA code ( I've moved away from plain **`gpuarrays`** in MATLAB ). I have experimented with **`.ptx`** kernels and **`MEX`**-files and have run into some roadblocks with both.

The parallel code has elementwise exponentiation, elementwise multiplication, and FFT and IFFT calls. It also incorporates complex numbers.

Are `.ptx` files compiled from CUDA-kernels or MEX CUDA files easier to work with and which will allow me to perform my necessary FFT, IFFT, exp, and mult calls?

Comment: Have You tried cuFFT (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html)?

Comment: I believe cuFFT is built into MATLAB's gpuArrray fft call. If that's the case, there's not much to improve on that front.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple really. You have to use MEX because you want to call into the NVIDIA cufft library, which you can only do from the host. However, there are basically no circumstances in which you will get a reasonable speed-up over calling FFT and IFFT from MATLAB, because those functions just call directly into cufft, with the added advantage of MATLAB's GPU memory pool and FFT plan cache. So maybe you should focus on the element-wise kernels.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I realized this problem too and think I will go with your solution of multiple kernels for the elementwise multiplication and exponentiation and call fft and ifft using MATLAB.

Comment: This is wrong. MATLAB's GPU implementation of the FFT is not in-place and does not offer real to complex transforms (by default).